# File/Database Online Sync in Android

Tags: java, android, database, dropbox, onedrive

I have an application for notes in which I save each entry in the database using SQLLite.
Now, I want to the users to able to sync the database online, so as to maintain a backup of the notes.
I came across DropBox and SkyDrive as the two most popular APIs for file sync, but I have not been able to get a working code.
Please help.
Code for any API would be helpful, either DropBox or SkyDrive or anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dropbox is using REST Api

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/api

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/start

If you don't know anything about REST Api try searching for REST API you will much material for your development

Comment: I got the code from the official DropBox site and tried to run it. Gives error. Can you please give me a working code ?

Answer (score 1):

Official sites for MS SkyDrive:
http://dev.live.com/
with links to github.com for SDK for iOS and Andorid

Live Interactive SDK at: http://isdk.dev.live.com/
is useful for debugging and testing what happens.